# Style Mapbox GL vector layer based on external data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm building an app with a Mapbox GL JS map. The map has a polygon layer that's being loaded in from a vector tileset hosted at Mapbox. The polygons aren't styled and don't contain the data I want to use to style them, however they do have unique IDs which I could use to join to other data within the scope of my JS app. Because this is a React app, I have that data stored in Redux.

What's the recommended way of joining the tileset layer to this external data? I suppose it's not important that it's in Redux -- it could just as easily be in a plain-old JS object -- but I'm a bit stumped on this one!

Comment: From what I remember about mapbox, you work with source vs. style layers. Reading up on those and how to use them might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a Mapbox example for joining data—I just didn't see it

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-join/